# Webpack 5 how to disable compression and left only minification

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, minify

I have a webpack project with a few js files:

package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
   
    "dev": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js --watch",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
...
```

webpack.prod.js

```
...
entry: {
        portal: `${portalDir}assets/js/portal.js`,
        branding: `${portalDir}assets/js/branding.js`,
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, `${portalDir}dist/js`),
        clean: true,
    },

    performance: {hints: false,},
...
```

portal.js

```
function demofunction(){console.log("demo");}
function demofunction2(){console.log("demo2");}
```

branding.js

```
function brandingfunction1(){console.log("br");}
function brandingfunction2(){console.log("br2");}
```

when i use the command

> npm run build

this command generate the files **dist/js/portal.js** and **dist/js/branding.js** but the code it's obfuscated or something, i want a builded file like:

portal.js

```
function demofunction(){console.log("demo");} function demofunction2(){console.log("demo2");}
```

The code is only minified but the result using **npm run build** generate something like:

```
(()=>{var e={};function t(e,t){....};})
```

Is there any way to only minify the js code? i try using:

```
optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: {
                compress: false,
                mangle: true,
                module: true,
            }
        })],
    },
```

in **webpack.prod.js** but it doesn't work.